# Azure Function Temp Files Clean Up

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure Function v2 with c#.net core code running on dedicated App Service Plan. The function downloads files and then uploads them via Microsoft Graph to a Sharepoint Library.

```
My code looks like this
 var path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + downloadedfileName;
 using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path)                
 {
    //put content from downloaded file into stream
    //call graph to use the stream and upload the content.
 }
```

This code works fine, but I am concerned about running out of temp space.
The question I have is:

1. When will this temp file get cleared
2. If it is not cleared automatically then how do i clear it?
3. Is there any other alternative way to handle this upload scenario?

Comment: if you want to make sure, why don't you just delete the file at the end of your code flow?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to know how these temp files are being handled by Azure Function App. If they are not getting cleared at all, then i will have to do as you suggested.

Comment: Since you are running in App Service Mode: this should be your answer (applies in the same way for Functons then) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247801/azure-web-app-temp-file-cleaning-responsibility

Comment: @AzureDev31 Yes, temporary files are not automatically cleared at all. You need to restart the startup site manually. Have a look of this doc: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look of [this doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files).

There is no automatic method, you can only do it manually. Since Azure Function is a Web App sandbox, if you don't delete files in your code, the method you can choose is the restart site provided in the doc.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @BowmanZhu. It would have been great if Azure function can handle clean up of unused files automatically instead of  we doing it manually via restarts. In my code now i have added the option to delete the file using using (var stream = File.Create(filename, buffersize, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose)). Do you think i can see this temp files in the D:/home directory?

Comment: @AzureDev31 No, it is not in the `D:/home`. It should be `D:\local\Temp>` and `D:\local\AppData>`. Use kudu tools go to that and then you can have a look.:)